# How to clear existing task and start entirely new task in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, task

In my Android app, I am launching my app from notification using below activity flags:

1. IntentCompat.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
2. Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
3. Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Still some activities of old task are getting visible on new launch.
Am I missing any flag?

Comment: have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line before you create the PendingIntent, but after that it depends of what you want to do exactly:

```
targetIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Intent loginscreen = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
loginscreen.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |     Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

startActivity(loginscreen);

this.finish();

I agree with @fab It is as good as logout functionality where in you want t clear all the flags values set by the user .
To Achieve the target android has provided Activity launch modes to launch activity

For detailed description go through [Link](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en)